# Android wear: very strange wait cycle

Tags: java, android, wait, alarm

I want my smartwatch vibrate every hour, so I created an alarm to a function that do the vibration.
Since it happens very often that android call the alarm function a couple of seconds later, I solved it so:

```
      final Thread t = new Thread()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

          try
          {
            Log.d(PROGRAM, "Waiting until next full minute");
            cal.setTimeInMillis(getCurrentTimeMillis());
            while(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) >= (60 - (HOURY_CHIME_CORRECTION / 1000)))
            {
              TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
              cal.setTimeInMillis(getCurrentTimeMillis());
            }
            hourlyChime();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            Log.i(PROGRAM, "Exception:\n" + e);
          }

          alarmManager.cancel(hourlyChimePendingIntent);
          alarmManager.setExact(
                  AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                  getNextHourMS(),
                  hourlyChimePendingIntent);
        }
      };
      t.start();
```

HOURLY_CHIME_CORRECTION is currently 10 seconds and the alarm is setted 10 seconds (HOURLY_CHIME_CORRECTION) before the full hour.

Now the problem: I see with ADB that the function will be called correctly (+/- a couple of seconds, as expected) and it starts the wait cycle.
Normally it works, but sometimes (**random!**) the cycle is blocked and it continues just if I turn the display on...
As I sayd, this behaviour ist **not reproducible** (or at least, not always). Sometimes works, sometimes not...

Has someone an idea, what can be the problem?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Never expect any background threads to keep executing when your app goes to the background. When your app is in the background Android can stop/kill its process whenever it sees fit (that's why it appears to be random).

Comment: Hi m0skit0, thank you very much. Do you mean, I have to move my code out of the Thread? It was already so, then I moved it in a Thread, since otherwise the display will not update during the function... Any idea, how to solve my problem?

Comment: I think your problem is that, once you receive the alarm broadcast from AlarmManager, your next alarm is not scheduled. Can you share about where you're scheduling the next alarm?

Comment: See the last part of my code...

Comment: I already saw that, I mean from where is this called?

Comment: Oh, sorry... the function will be called from the alarm receiver. This can not be the problem, since the function will always be called... This evening I'll try to rewrite the wait cycle without Thread and with an invalidate() in the cycle, hoping this don't block the display update and works...

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that while loop in the main thread that calls the receiver either. I don't understand what are you trying to achieve with that loop, can you explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

I have a "solution"... A **very hugly** one...
Since I cannot wait in a Thread beeing sure the system will not cancel the Thread, and since waiting without Thread result in blocking the display update, I wrote two different wait cycles: the first one in a Thread, running if display is **on** and the other one, without Thread, running if display is **off**.

Of course the problem is that if the display goes on during the second wait cycle, nothing will be displayed...

I tried to force the refresh of the display inside the wait cycle, but I didn't got it working. Calling invalidate() does not work... No display updates will be done.
I suppose, invalidate() just says the system "as soon as you can, redraw the view", but as long as the program is in the wait cycle the system does not redraw...
Maybe someone know a system to redraw the watchface during a for-loop? This will be the **right** solution, of course...

Regards
Luca